# How to manually define place for blog post preview using Django and CKEditor?

Tags: html, django, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a blog written in Python + Django.

Before I started use of WYSIWYG editor, to create a blog post preview I manually added custom html tag `<post_cut/>` and used python slice to show only a preview. It allowed to avoid issues with fixed length for preview or breaking html tags.

Now I added [Django-CKEditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) and it removes all html tags which "it doesn't understand".

I tried to do something with configuration (`allowedContentRules`, `format_tags` and etc.) but no success.

The questions is how to manage "post-cut" and how to do this using CKEditor.
P.S. it would be awesome also to have button for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by myself.
You need to use [extraAllowedContent](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent) if you want to add some extra tags.

Also found how to add custom button [by creating a custom plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample.html).
But still looking for good solution that will utilize [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'extraAllowedContent': {
            'post_cut': True,
        },
        # ...
        # (other options)
    }
}
```